# Why Would Remote Execution of a Query Cause it to be Suspended?

Tags: sql-server, jpa, view

I apologize in advance for not having all of the specifics available, but the machine is building an index probably for a good while still and is almost completely unresponsive.

I've got a table on SQL Server 2005 with a good number of columns, maybe 20, but a mammoth number of rows (tens, more likely hundreds of millions). In order to simplify the amount of JPA work I'd need to do to access it, I created a view that contained the bits I was interested in. The view was created as:

```
SELECT bigtable.ID, bigtable.external_identification, mediumtable.hostname,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, bigtable.datefield, 121) AS datefield
FROM schema.bigtable JOIN schema.mediumtable ON bigtable.joinID = mediumtable.ID;
```

When I want to select from the view, I do:

```
SELECT * FROM vwTable WHERE external_identification = 'some string';
```

This works just fine in SQL Management Studio. The external_identification column has a non-unique, non-clustered index in bigtable. This also worked just fine on our remotely executing Java program in our test environment. Now that we're a day or two away from production, the code has been changed a bit (although the fundamental JPA NamedQuery is still straightforward), but we have a new SQLServer installation on new hardware; the test version was on a 32-bit single core machine, the new hardware is 64-bit multi-core.

Whenever I try to run the code that uses this view on the new hardware, it either hangs indefinitely on the first call of this query or times out if I have a timeout specified. After doing some digging, something like:

```
SELECT status, command, wait_type, last_wait_type FROM sys.dm_exec_requests;
```

confirmed that the query was running, but showed it in the state:

```
suspended, SELECT, CXPACKET, CXPACKET
```

for as long as I cared to wait for it. Whenever I ran the exact same query from within the Management Studio, it completed immediately. So I did some research, and found out this is due to waiting on some kind of concurrent operation to start/finish. In an attempt to circumvent that, I set the server-wide MAXDOP to 1 (disabled concurrency). After that, the query still hangs, but the sys.dm_exec_requests would show:

```
suspended, SELECT, PAGEIOLATCH_SH, PAGEIOLATCH_SH
```

This indicates that it's some sort of HD/scanning issue. While certainly the machine is less responsive than I'd expect for newer hardware, I wouldn't expect this query (even over the view) to require much scanning, since the column I'm searching by is indexed in the underlying table and it works if I run it locally. But just because I'm out of ideas and under the gun, I'm adding indexes to the view; first I have to add the unique clustered index (over ID) before I can attempt to add the non-unique non-clustered index over external_identification.

I'm the only one using this database; when I select from sys.dm_exec_requests the only two results are the query I'm actively inspecting and the select from sys.dm_exec_requests query. So it's not like it's under legitimately heavy, or even at all concurrent, load.

But I suspect I'm grasping at straws. I'm no DBA, and every time I have to interact with SQL Server outside of querying it it baffles my intuitions. Does anyone have any ideas why a query executed remotely would immediately go into a suspended state while the same query locally would execute immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this one caught me straight out of left field. It turns out that by default, the MSSQL JDBC driver sends its String datatypes as Unicode, which the table/view might not be prepared to handle specifically. In our case, the columns and indexes were not, so MSSQL would perform a full table scan for each lookup.

In our test environment, the table was small enough that this didn't matter, so I was tricked into thinking it worked fine. In retrospect, I'm glad it didn't -- I can't stand it when computers give the illusion of inconsistency.

When I added this little parameter to the end of my JDBC connection string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[IP]:1433;databaseName=[db];sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
```

things immediately and magically started working. Sorry for the slightly misleading question (I barely even mentioned JPA), but I had no idea what the cause was and really did believe it was something SQL Server side. Task Manager didn't report heavy CPU/Memory usage while the query was suspended, so I just thought it was idling even though it was really under heavy disk usage.

More info about MSSQL JDBC and Unicode can be found where I stumbled across the solution, at http://server.pramati.com/blog/2010/06/02/perfissues-jdbcdrivers-mssqlserver/ . Thanks, Ed, for that detailed shot in the dark -- it may not have been the problem, but I certainly learned a lot (and fast!) about MSSQL's gritty parts!

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the query run in SSMS and by your application are using different query plans - from the wait types you're seeing in `dm_exec_requests` it sounds like the plan created for the application is doing a table scan where the plan for SSMS is using an index seek.

This is possible because the SSMS and application database connections likely use different connection options, some of which are used as a key to the database plan cache.

You can find out which options your application is using by running a default [SQL server profiler trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) against the server; the first command after the connection is created will be a number of `SET...` options:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
...
```

I suspect this list will be different between your application and your SSMS connection - a common candidate is `SET ARITHABORT {ON|OFF}`, since that forms part of the key of the cached plan.
If you run the `SET...` commands in an SSMS window before executing the query, the same (bad) plan as is being used by the application should then be picked up.

Assuming this demonstrates the problem, the next step is to work out how to prevent the bad plan getting into cache. It's difficult to give generic instructions about how to do this, since there are a few possible causes.
It's a bit of a scattergun approach (there are other more targetted ways to attempt to resolve this problem but they require more detailed understanding of the issue that I have now), but one thing to try is to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of your query - this forces a new plan to be generated for every execution, and should prevent the bad plan being reused:

```
SELECT * FROM vwTable WHERE external_identification = 'some string' OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Assuming you can replicate the bad performance is SSMS using the steps above, you should be able to test this there.
Beware that this can have negative performance consequences if the query is executed very frequently (since each recompilation requires CPU) - this depends on the workload of your application and will need testing.

A couple of other thoughts:

Check the schemas between the test and production systems; this might be as simple as a missing index from one of the tables in the production database, although given that SSMS queries perform OK this is unlikely.

You should re-enable parallelism by taking the server-wide `MAXDOP=1` off, since this will limit the performance of your system overall. The problem is almost certainly the query plan, not parallelism

You also need to beware of the consequences of adding indexes to the view - doing so effectively materialises the view, which will (given the size of the table) require a lot of storage overhead - the indexes will also need to be maintained when `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements take place on the base table. Indexing the view is probably unnecessary given that (from SSMS) you know it's possible for the query to perform.

Comment: Wow, very informative considering how much guesswork went into my post. +1 already. I'll get to testing this as soon as I'm able, but creating the index on the view was definitely a bad idea -- 18 hours later and it's still running. I'm going to look into how to cancel it, although I've heard say that it will take as long to cancel as it's been running.

Comment: @HammerBro. - I think it's correct to say that if you cancel now rolling back the index creation will take as long as the operation has so far - all the entries in the transaction log will have to be undone. Keep an eye on the size of the transaction log whilst the index creation operation is going on - it's likely to require a lot of space.

Comment: Thankfully, the rollback only took ~15 minutes. Now I'm wrestling with the Profiler Trace. I just found the SET options you're talking about, and they're identical between my program's remote connection and the local SSMS one, minus the network protocol comment, which means it's got to be something else going wrong. But I'm stumped as to any meaningful differences between local/remote or between here and the working test environment. Tangentially, I've set MAXDOP=0 again and do not intend to do any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETEs.